# How to retrieve text inside a text field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Consider the HTML of a text field.

```
<input id="employeeId" class="formInputText" type="text" value="0013" name="employeeId" maxlength="10"/>
```

I want to retrieve the value inside `value=""` attribute of the text box and store it in a string variable.

I have constructed the xpath of the text field as:

```
//input[@id='employeeId']
```

I have following code:

```
driver.findElement(Btn_Save).click();

boolean mandatory_firstName = (first_Name != null && !first_Name.isEmpty() && !first_Name.trim().isEmpty());
boolean mandatory_lastName = (last_Name != null && !last_Name.isEmpty() && !last_Name.trim().isEmpty());
boolean mandatory_userName = (user_Name != null && !user_Name.isEmpty() && !user_Name.trim().isEmpty());
boolean mandatory_Password = (Pass != null && !Pass.isEmpty() && !Pass.trim().isEmpty());
boolean mandatory_ConfPass = (Confirm_Pass != null && !Confirm_Pass.isEmpty() && !Confirm_Pass.trim().isEmpty());

if((mandatory_firstName && mandatory_lastName && mandatory_userName && mandatory_Password && mandatory_ConfPass) == false)
    {
        Assert.fail("Error: One of the mandatory fields is missing text. \n");
    }

else
    {
        boolean PassConfirmation = (Pass.equals(Confirm_Pass));
        if(PassConfirmation == false)
        {
            Assert.fail("Error: Password and Confirm Password did not match. Run Test again with same passwords. \n");
        }
        else
        {
            WebElement employeeID = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='employeeId']"));
            String empID = employeeID.getText();
            System.out.println("ID is: "+empID);
        }
    }
```

THis piece of code starts with clicking the save button. It then checks for mandatory fields and password, confirm password. 
On the same page, there is a text field of employee id, and it contains some pre-set value. I want to extract that value. I tried to make webelement of the field and getText() it, but when I run my script, it gives me NOSuchElementFound exception and stack trace refers me to `WebElement employeeID = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='employeeId']"));` command.

Comment: Once you have the WebElement that represents the input field, just call getText() on it?

Comment: Yeah, about that. Already tried that, but for some reason when I use WebElement, my script throws NoSuchElementFound exception. Will edit the post with my piece of code.

Comment: Ah yeah, I didn't read the question properly. It's an input field, not an element with a TextNode within it. I reckon Karthik has your answer right there.

Comment: getText only return text value but this is attribute value, you need to user String empID = employeeID.getAttribute()

Comment: @Uziii sounds like you need to wait for the element to be visible, and if it never become visible figure out why it's actually not visible.

Answer (score 2):

Get the desired attribute as shown below

```
String valAttr = driver.findElement(By.id("employeeId")).getAttribute("value");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
String value =   driver.findElement(By.id("employeeId")).getCssValue("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's way you can get value of an attribute of a WebElement -

```
String empID = driver.findElement(By.id("employeeId")).getAttribute("value");
```

If you want to make use of empID in integer form then use below code -

```
int empIDval = Integer.parseInt(empID);
```